# R: Function that creates a new column and assigns a score based off of the difference

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function that calculates a score based off of the user inputs of a cost and a weight.  I am trying to subtract the user input from a column in the dataframe passed into the function and then assign a score based off of the difference and the user inputs for the weight.  I then wish to add this column to the dataframe.  However, I'm having difficulty getting it to work properly.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am basically just trying to assign a score to a school based off the difference between the user's input of costs and the school's actual cost. So, for instance, if the user wants a cost of 25000 and the school costs 15000, then I want it to give this school a maximum score. If the cost of the school significantly exceeds the user's input cost, then I want to give this a low score. I want it to calculate the score for each row in my data frame.  Here's what I have so far.

```
distance = function(table, a, weighta) {
 dist = c((table$In.state.tuition - a))
 if (any(dist <= 0)) {
     score = 10
 }
 else score = 0

finalscore = weighta*score
table$Score = finalscore 
return(table)
}
```

Comment: You need to describe your expected output. This is best done using some example input data and the intended output of the function for those inputs.

Comment: I am basically just trying to assign a score to a school based off the difference between the user's input of costs and the school's actual cost.  So, for instance, if the user wants a cost of 25000 and the school costs 15000, then I want it to give this school a maximum score.  If the cost of the school significantly exceeds the user's input cost, then I want to give this a low score.  I want it to calculate the score for each column in my data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I got it to work using the ifelse function.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what your question is, or what code you've tried, but it seems to me that you want to award a score of `10*weighta` to the scools with tuitions under some user-defined threshold. If it's so, I think this is easily obtained by standard code (I used some random values):

```
set.seed(123)                                     # make it reproducible
df<-data.frame(In.state.tuition =rnorm(20,50,2), score=rep(0,20))
a<-49                                             # arbitrary number
weighta<-3                                        # another arbitrary number
df$score[df$In.state.tuition<=a]<-10*weighta      # use indexing
df
   In.state.tuition score
1          48.87905    30
2          49.53965     0
3          53.11742     0
4          50.14102     0
5          50.25858     0
6          53.43013     0
7          50.92183     0
8          47.46988    30
9          48.62629    30
10         49.10868     0
11         52.44816     0
12         50.71963     0
13         50.80154     0
14         50.22137     0
15         48.88832    30
16         53.57383     0
17         50.99570     0
18         46.06677    30
19         51.40271     0
20         49.05442     0
```

Is this what you wanted?

As a sidenote, I guess from your last comment in your question where you state "I want to calculate a score for each column" that you actually meant "I want to calculate a score for each **row** in the `In.state.tuition` column".